# partial least squares for comparing two classes

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, partial-least-squares

I have one data set labeled by two classes either A or B. I did PLS and I extracted the variable importance.

```
    overal
v3  100
v5  38.77046648
v9  34.2419393
v32 30.14106059
v7  28.7229834
v56 26.37437813
v76 25.72790586
...
```

If I got it correctly, the variable importance shows the relative importance of the features for distinguishing (classification) of A and B. But how can we show, for instance, these features are belong to which class, A or B? is there anyway to do that? e.g. v3 is belong to A or B?

Comment: You are looking for classification or importance of features? I mean, where is A or B label in your data?

Comment: importance of features. My goal is to find those feature in A and B that can distinguish two classes.